# Does Pytest cache fixture data when called by multiple test functions?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have unit tests that require test data. This test data is downloaded and has decently large filesize.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def large_data_file():
    large_data = download_some_data('some_token')
    return large_data

# Perform tests with input data
def test_foo(large_data_file): pass
def test_bar(large_data_file): pass
def test_baz(large_data_file): pass
# ... and so on
```

I do not want to download this data more than once. It should only be downloaded once, and passed to all the tests that require it. Does pytest call on `large_data_file` once and use it for every unit test that uses that fixture, or does it call the `large_data_file` each time?

In `unittest`, you would simply download the data for all the tests once in the `setUpClass` method.

I would rather not just have a global `large_data_file = download_some_data('some_token')` in this py script. I would like to know how to handle this use-case with Pytest.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Does pytest call on `large_data_file` once and use it for every unit test that uses that fixture, or does it call the `large_data_file` each time?

It depends on the fixture scope. The default scope is `function`, so in your example `large_data_file` will be evaluated three times. If you broaden the scope, e.g.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def large_data_file():
    ...
```

the fixture will be evaluated once per test session and the result will be cached and reused in all dependent tests. Check out the section [Scope: sharing fixtures across classes, modules, packages or session](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/fixtures.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session) in `pytest` docs for more details.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @hoefling's answer, here's a practical example:

```py
# ran only once
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def good_password():
    pwd = "Open, Sesame!"
    hpw = bcrypt.hashpw(pw.encode(), bcrypt.gensalt()).decode()  # slow
    return pwd, hpw


# ran for each test
@pytest.fixture
def good_user(db, good_password):
    name = "Ali Baba"
    pwd, hpw = good_password
    db.insert_user(username=name, password_hash=hpw)  # fast
    return name, pwd


def test_login(good_user, client):
    name, pwd = good_user
    r = client.post("/login", form={"username": name, "password": pwd})
    r.raise_for_status()


def test_smth_else(good_user, client):
    ...
```